Computing a challenging derivative with intergrals
I'm struggling to compute a derivative.
Consider
\begin{equation}
Y = \left( \left( \int_{N-1}^{I} \eta(i)^{\sigma-1} \, di \right)^{\frac{1}{\sigma}} K^{\frac{\sigma-1}{\sigma}} 
+ \left( \int_{I}^{N} \gamma(i)^{\sigma-1} \, di \right)^{\frac{1}{\sigma}} L^{\frac{\sigma-1}{\sigma}} \right)^{\frac{\sigma}{\sigma-1}}
\end{equation}
where $\sigma$ is a parameter, $\sigma \in [0, + \infty)$.
The derivative I have to compute is
\begin{equation}
\frac{d \,ln \,Y}{d \, I}
\end{equation}
where the following optimality condition at a certain point can be exploited (I'll present the expression without delving into its economic implications, as the question will be purely on the calculus aspect): i) $R = \int_{N-1}^{I} \eta(i) \, di $
and ii) $W = \int_{I}^{N} \gamma(i) \,di$
My attempt below
\begin{equation}
\frac{d \,ln \,Y}{d \, I} = \frac{d Y}{d \, I} \frac{1}{Y}
\end{equation}
I set, $Z(I)= \left( \int_{N-1}^{I} \eta(i)^{\sigma-1} \, di \right)^{\frac{1}{\sigma}} K^{\frac{\sigma-1}{\sigma}} 
+ \left( \int_{I}^{N} \gamma(i)^{\sigma-1} \, di \right)^{\frac{1}{\sigma}} L^{\frac{\sigma-1}{\sigma}}$
Thus,
\begin{equation}
Y = Z(I)^{\frac{\sigma}{\sigma-1}}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{d Y}{d I} = \frac{\sigma}{\sigma -1} Z(I)^{\frac{1}{\sigma -1}} \frac{d Z}{d \, I}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{d Z}{d I} = \frac{1}{\sigma } \left( \int_{N-1}^{I} \eta(i)^{\sigma-1} \, di \right)^{\frac{1- \sigma}{\sigma}} \eta(I)^{\sigma -1} K^{\frac{\sigma-1}{\sigma}} 
- \frac{1}{\sigma} \left( \int_{I}^{N} \gamma(i)^{\sigma-1} \, di \right)^{\frac{1 - \sigma}{\sigma}} \gamma(I)^{\sigma -1} L^{\frac{\sigma-1}{\sigma}}
\end{equation}
Using i) $R = \int_{N-1}^{I} \eta(i) \, di $   and ii) $W = \int_{I}^{N} \gamma(i) \,di$, I write
\begin{equation}
\frac{d Z}{d I} = \frac{1}{\sigma } \left( R^{\sigma-1}  \right)^{\frac{1- \sigma}{\sigma}} \eta(I)^{\sigma -1} K^{\frac{\sigma-1}{\sigma}} 
- \frac{1}{\sigma} \left(W^{\sigma-1}  \right)^{\frac{1 - \sigma}{\sigma}} \gamma(I)^{\sigma -1} L^{\frac{\sigma-1}{\sigma}}
\end{equation}
Using this result in the expression above for $\frac{d Y}{d I}$
\begin{equation}
\frac{d Y}{d I} = \frac{\sigma}{\sigma -1} Z(I)^{\frac{1}{\sigma -1}} \left[ \frac{1}{\sigma } \left( R^{\sigma-1}  \right)^{\frac{1- \sigma}{\sigma}} \eta(I)^{\sigma -1} K^{\frac{\sigma-1}{\sigma}} 
- \frac{1}{\sigma} \left(W^{\sigma-1}  \right)^{\frac{1 - \sigma}{\sigma}} \gamma(I)^{\sigma -1} L^{\frac{\sigma-1}{\sigma}} \right]
\end{equation}
and since $Z(I)= \left( \int_{N-1}^{I} \eta(i)^{\sigma-1} \, di \right)^{\frac{1}{\sigma}} K^{\frac{\sigma-1}{\sigma}} 
+ \left( \int_{I}^{N} \gamma(i)^{\sigma-1} \, di \right)^{\frac{1}{\sigma}} L^{\frac{\sigma-1}{\sigma}} = (RK)^{\frac{\sigma -1}{\sigma}} +(WL)^{\frac{\sigma -1}{\sigma}}$, I write
\begin{equation}
\frac{d Y}{d I} = \frac{1}{\sigma - 1} \left[ \left( RK \right)^{\frac{\sigma - 1}{\sigma}} + \left( WL \right)^{\frac{\sigma - 1}{\sigma}} \right]^{\frac{1}{\sigma - 1}} \left[ \left( R^{\sigma - 1} \right)^{\frac{1 - \sigma}{\sigma}} \eta(I)^{\sigma - 1} K^{\frac{\sigma - 1}{\sigma}} 
-  \left( W^{\sigma - 1} \right)^{\frac{1 - \sigma}{\sigma}} \gamma(I)^{\sigma - 1} L^{\frac{\sigma - 1}{\sigma}} \right]
\end{equation}
And,
\begin{equation}
\frac{d \, ln \, Y}{d I} = \frac{1}{\sigma - 1} \left[ \left( RK \right)^{\frac{\sigma - 1}{\sigma}} + \left( WL \right)^{\frac{\sigma - 1}{\sigma}} \right]^{\frac{1 - \sigma}{\sigma - 1}} \left[ \left( R^{\sigma - 1} \right)^{\frac{1 - \sigma}{\sigma}} \eta(I)^{\sigma - 1} K^{\frac{\sigma - 1}{\sigma}} 
-  \left( W^{\sigma - 1} \right)^{\frac{1 - \sigma}{\sigma}} \gamma(I)^{\sigma - 1} L^{\frac{\sigma - 1}{\sigma}} \right]
\end{equation}
At this stage, the computation becomes complicated and I'm not able to get the final result which, according to the book, is
\begin{equation}
\frac{d \ln Y}{dI} = \frac{1}{1 - \sigma} \left[ \left( \frac{W}{\gamma(I)} \right)^{1 - \sigma} - \left( \frac{R}{\eta(I)} \right)^{1 - \sigma} \right]
\end{equation}

Your $\frac{d Z}{d I} = \frac1\sigma\left( R^{\sigma-1}  \right)^{\frac{1- \sigma}{\sigma}} \eta(I)^{\sigma -1} K^{\frac{\sigma-1}{\sigma}}
-\dots$ is wrong because $\int_{N-1}^I\eta(i)^{\sigma-1} , di\ne R^{\sigma-1}$.

I see, I was not sure about this point. Thanks for pointing out the mistake. How do you seggest to proceed in a way to exploit optimal conditions i) and ii)? Should I write $\int_{N-1}^{I} \eta(i)^{\sigma -1} $ as $(1/\sigma) [\eta^{\sigma } (I)- \eta^{\sigma } (N-1)]$,  and then look for some simplifications?


I don't understand i) and ii). I first thought they were just notations. Are $R$ and $W$ some constants (independent from $I$)? This seems impossible. 2) $\int_{N-1}^{I} \eta(i)^{\sigma -1}di\ne(1/\sigma) [\eta^{\sigma } (I)- \eta^{\sigma } (N-1)]$.


Some hypothesis seem to be missing to reach the "final result". What book is it? Or even better: can you please include a complete screenshot?

It comes from the article Modeling Automation by Acemoglu and Restrepo (AEA 2018) and pertains to economics. $R(t)$ and $W(t)$ are not constant, as they are functions of time. I have suppressed the $t$ for the sake of notation. In fact, conditions (i) and (ii) are two first-order conditions: $y(i,t) = \eta(i,t) k(i,t)$, with $i \in [N-1, I]$. Aggregating, we have: $Y_k = \int_{N-1}^{I} \eta(i,t) k(i,t) , di = \left( \int_{N-1}^{I} \eta(i,t) , di \right) K(t)$, with $K(t)=\int_{N-1}^{I}k(i,t)di$. The FOC is:
$\frac{\partial Y_k}{\partial K} = R(t)$.A similar concept applies to $W(t)$.

The second FOC comes from: $y(i,t) = \gamma(i,t) l(i,t)$, with $i \in (I, N]$ and aggregating:
$$
Y_L = \int_{I}^{N} \gamma(i,t) l(i,t) , di = \left( \int_{I}^{N} \gamma(i,t) , di \right) L(t),
$$
where $L(t) = \int_{I}^{N} l(i,t) , di$. I'm sorry to delve into the economics concepts, but this is the only place where I can get valuable answers when mathematics is involved.

I'm sorry: despite my efforts I am not able to help. I give up. My "final result" is
$$\frac{d \ln Y}{dI} = \frac{1}{1 - \sigma} \left[ \left( \frac B{\gamma(I)} \right)^{1 - \sigma} - \left( \frac A{\eta(I)} \right)^{1 - \sigma} \right]$$
where $A=\left(\frac YK\int_{N-1}^I\eta^{\sigma-1}\right)^{1/\sigma}$ and $B=\left(\frac YL\int_I^N\gamma^{\sigma-1}\right)^{1/\sigma}$.

Thanks so much for the answer. To learn from my mathematical mistake, could you briefly post an answer showing, in just a few steps, how you arrived at your final result? I'd be happy to upvote your response.

Not an answer but (upon request by OP's comment) a proof of an alternative "final result".
$$Y^\frac{\sigma-1}\sigma=\alpha R_\sigma+\beta W_\sigma$$
where $$R_\sigma:=\left(\int_{N-1}^I\eta^{\sigma-1}\right)^{1/\sigma},\quad W_\sigma:=\left(\int_I^N\gamma^{\sigma-1}\right)^{1/\sigma},\quad\alpha:= K^{\frac{\sigma-1}\sigma},\quad\beta:=L^{\frac{\sigma-1}\sigma}.$$
Therefore,
$$\ln Y=\frac\sigma{\sigma-1}\ln\left(\alpha R_\sigma+\beta W_\sigma\right)$$ and
$$\begin{align}\frac{d\ln Y}{dI}&=\frac\sigma{(\sigma-1)\left(\alpha R_\sigma+\beta W_\sigma\right)}\left(\alpha\frac{dR_\sigma}{dI}+\beta\frac{dW_\sigma}{dI}\right)\\&=\frac1{(\sigma-1)Y^\frac{\sigma-1}\sigma}\left(\alpha R_\sigma^{1-\sigma}\eta(I)^{\sigma-1}-\beta W_\sigma^{1-\sigma}\gamma(I)^{\sigma-1}\right)\\&=\frac1{1-\sigma}\left[\left(\frac B{\gamma(I)}\right)^{1-\sigma}-\left(\frac A{\eta(I)}\right)^{1-\sigma} \right]
\end{align}$$
where $A=\left(\frac YK\int_{N-1}^I\eta^{\sigma-1}\right)^{1/\sigma}$ and $B=\left(\frac YL\int_I^N\gamma^{\sigma-1}\right)^{1/\sigma}$.
